# VS 2008 macros disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2008, macros

Suddenly, my macros are not running in MS Visual Studio 2008.  For example, to ensure that we don't care too much about Unicode or not, we wrap all hardcoded strings in _T().  So, I created a tiny macro named "InitializeString".  All it does is to enter _T(""), and then move the cursor back two spaces so it's between the quotation marks.  I assigned this macro to the Ctrl/Shift/S combination.  It's been extremely helpful.  But suddenly, I hit Ctrl/Shift/S and nothing happens!  I tried opening the macro explorer, right-clicking on a macro, and selecting Run.  Still nothing.  I tried recording a temporary macro that just consisted of typing a string of "s"s.  When I hit Ctrl/Shift/P to play it back, VS 2008 thought about it for a moment as it usually does the first time a macro is invoked, and then -- nothing.

I checked my options, and the "Allow Macros To Run" box is checked.

What could be happening?

Thanks very much!

RobR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue caused by a recent Windows update. See [Visual Studio 2010 Macros Stop Working after February 2014 Windows Update](http://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2014/02/13/visual-studio-2010-macros-stop-working-after-february-2014-windows-update/) for solutions how to fix it.

Comment: Many thanks!  The "AllowDComReflection" changes worked for me.

Comment: Same here in VS2008.. the "AllowDComReflection" changes in 3 config files fixed it for me.