# Visual Studio 2008 Macro Keyboard Shortcuts Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-2008, macros

I have several macros that I use on a daily basis in VS2008. E.g. one to expand all regions in a file. I assigned the macros a keyboard shortcut and everything was fine and good.

This morning I came to work, and being a Monday, of course they have stopped working. I have unloaded/reloaded the macro project via Macro Explorer. The EnvironmentEvents macros are triggered by the various events, but my keyboard shortcut ones do not. If I debug the macro the breakpoint is never even hit. I have created a new macro project and added a new macro to it and the same thing is happening. I have gone as far as to reset VS2008 in every way, shape and form before uninstalling it.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this has happened or how I can get my macros running again?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944116/vs-2008-macros-disabled

Comment: That is indeed the fix.